# Allophones: /e/ as [j] , /kj/ as [k͡xj]?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

I noticed a few pronunciations which surprised me.

In [this clip](https://youtu.be/MQmJYGBpBXM?t=20m8s), and in a lot of other movies, 返して, /kaeɕ.te/ sounds like [kaɪ̯ɕ.te] to me. Is there a rule?:
/e/ → [ɪ̯] / a_ .
If so: Is it dialectal, slang or standard pronunciation?

It sounds to me like the name 桔梗, ききょう, /ki.kjoː/, is consistently pronounced [kʰi.k͡xjoː] in [Inuyasha](https://youtu.be/4Iw8G4aKtRk?t=37s).
Rule:
/kj/ → [k͡xj] / i_
???

Comment: By [[x]] do you mean [[ç]]? I would have maybe written [[kç.k͡çjoː]].

Comment: Could you please edit your question? You're mixing up <y> (an orthographic character) with /j/ (a phonetic character) which is rather confusing. /y/ is a French and German sound.

Comment: No, in the question body the OP is correctly using /y/ as a language-specific phonemic symbol and [j] as a phonetic symbol, which is fairly standard for Japanese transcriptions.  The question title uses /j/, however, which is confusing.

Comment: I changed the missleading "y" to "j". With "j" I mean the palatal approximant. You're right Earthliŋ, [ç] is better than [x]. However, I still hear an [i]. So for me it sounds like [kçi.k͡çjoː]. I have only encountered this pronouncition with that particular name so far... However, I hear [ɪ̯] instead of [e] quite often in syllable final position.

Comment: @snailboat Your typical Japanese transcriptions are chiefly for romanization (so that people unfamiliar with the Japanese script can get a basic idea of what the words should sound like) or very, very specific Japanese language-related contexts (for example, when you're only talking about Japanese and don't want to be bothered by inconvenient phonetic characters). But when you start using IPA, use IPA properly, and don't mix things up for unnecessary confusion. As far as I know, only /ʃ/ is an acceptable broad transcription for [ɕ]. [j] is still /j/.

Comment: /ae/ sometimes does sound like /aɪ/, but I rather hear this 返して pronounced more retracted or centralized than higher.